# VueX state is always undefined in mutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, state, vuex

I got a problem with my `VueX` store. When i call my actions the fetch is ok and i got response data.
When i want to store the response into rps i call my mutations `setRps()`.

And i got this error

[error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHScu.png)

I've try to see what's inside state i got : undefined.

So i don't understand why my state is undefined and in my other store no.

my code :

```
import Rp from '../config/rp-manager'

const state = {
    rps: {},
}

const actions = {
    getRps({ commit }) {
        Rp().get('/rps').then(response => {
            commit('setRps', response.data)
        })
    }
}

const mutations = {

    setRps(state, data) {
        state.rps = data
    }

}


export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's possible that you used the store incorrectly

Comment: Your data passing to the mutation may be null or undefined. Try an alternative value to catch that. `state.rps = data ?? {}`

Comment: Please post an error message as text not an image.

Comment: `console.log` is your best friend. Put it on strategic places in your functions and you will find out where does this `undefined` come from.